# What do you do to scan with 600 dpi while maintaing a small output file?

Tags: pdf, compression, scanner

I just installed xsane which I already successfully tested with my Epson Perfection V30. When scanning with these settings

[image: xsane settings for a4, 600 dpi and color]

the output file is remarkably large. Is there a way to decrease the size, preferably by built-in settings/options in xsane?

Comment: So I suppose the common way then is to use something like ImageMagick or another tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to reduce the size of the image is to save it in a compressed format such as jpg or png. After the scan when the image viewer pops up, select save image and give the filename a `.jpg` or `.png` extension. It varies depending on the image, but 600 DPI scan compressed should result in around 0.5MBs.

Comment: I am looking to clone my Windows behavior actually, meaning in the long term I'd like to run some ocr software on the PDF files I produce based (in)directly on scanning output. So in that sense, I think outputting a pdf file from the scan is easier/more comfortable. However, your suggestion yielded also [a file with a size of over 50 MB.](http://imgur.com/PpnLzrP)

Comment: Which file type did it save as? Just as a TIFF with the extension.jpeg or in actual JFIF format?  (Use the command `file file_to_test.jpeg`_.

Comment: Hm, you are actually right: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6704668/

Comment: For the sake of completeness, if anyone else is reading here for a solution: JPG file size is considerably smaller than a PNG file.